# How to reset cursor color in bash

Tags: bash, shell

This happens to me on Linux, not on a Mac. When I use `tput setaf` and then `tput sgr0`, the cursor still remains in the previously selected colour, until I press return again. I can reset it the same way by just doing `echo ''`, but that isn't ideal as it creates a new line for me. Using `printf` didn't work either.

How can I reset the cursor color in the shell?

[image: Color change fails]
[image: Echo kind of helps]

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce this; it seems to be depend on your terminal emulator.

Comment: I'm SSH'ed into an ubuntu machine from iTerm on a Mac.

Answer (score 6):

```
tput sgr0
```

restore the settings to default colour - and it works fine for me (I don't need another echo).

To solve your situation I suggest to use this code:

```
tput setaf 2 && echo -en 'Name: ' && tput sgr0 && echo ""
```

Comment: To use this in your own software without having to spawn a tput process, you can observe what tput does by piping it into a file or a hexdump program like this: `tput sgr0 | hexdump`. Then, in your own software, you can just replicate the part you need, which seems to be `print("\x1b[m")` (frequently written as `\033[m`).

Answer (score 5):

#### Short answer

```
echo -n -e '\e[?0c'
```

---

#### Long answer

As of today, the current version of *a*ge**tty** (contained in `util-linux 2.27.1` [util-linux is the linux package providing most core commands, like `login`, `su`, `mount`, `more`, `kill` - to name a few] - and you should have it if your linux kernel version is >=4.4) has a different behavior than described in the yet-to-be-updated kernel.org documentation ([Software cursor for VGA](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/VGA-softcursor.txt)).

Consider

`echo -n -e '\e[?`*byte1*`;`*byte2*`;`*byte3*`c'`

byte1:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  |   |   |   +-+
                  |   |   |     |   These bits specify the 8
                  |   |   +-----+-> possible blinking HW carets
                  |   |         |   
                  |   +---------+
                  |
                  +---------------> When set, this bit enables SW
                                    caret instead of HW caret
```

byte2 (SW caret):

```
                +-----------------> A pretty useless mask applied
                |                   to bits in byte3
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

byte3 (SW caret):

```
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   +-------------------> Highlighting
  |   |   |
  |   |   +---------------------+
  |   |                         |
  |   +-------------------------+-> Color
  |                             |
  +-----------------------------+
```

Highlighting: highligths the character beneath the caret (e.g. changing it to white [true shiny white] instead of dark white [the light gray that is commonly the default for TTYs]).

Color: the color of the caret. Note that, compared to the usual order of ANSI color codes we all know and love, bits are reversed, so -for this triplet- the 7th is the **L**sb while the 5th is the **M**sb.

So, while in the 70s ANSI defined the following color codes, setting a *de-facto* standard adopted universally for TTYs, miscellaneous linux terminals, consoles, and whatnot

```
000 (0) black
001 (1) red
010 (2) green
011 (3) yellow or dark yellow
100 (4) blue or dark blue
101 (5) magenta, purple or violet
110 (6) cyan or light blue
111 (7) white or dark white (light gray)
```

in this case we have the opposite

```
000 (0) black
100 (4) red
010 (2) green
110 (6) yellow or dark yellow
001 (1) blue or dark blue
101 (5) magenta, purple or violet
011 (3) cyan or light blue
111 (7) white or dark white (light gray)
```

*(Octal value parenthesized)*

So, here comes the list:

```
#Hardware carets (blinking and [dark ]white)
echo -n -e '\e[?0c' #default caret
echo -n -e '\e[?1c' #invisible caret
echo -n -e '\e[?2c' #underscore caret
echo -n -e '\e[?3c' #thicker underscore caret
echo -n -e '\e[?4c' #smaller block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?5c' #small block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?6c' #big block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?7c' #biggest block caret
#On my Linux machine, both 6 and 7 are the big rectangular full-size block caret

#Software carets (non-blinking and colored)
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;0c'  #00001000 0 00000000 black (thus invisible on black background)
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;128c'#00001000 0 10000000 red
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;64c' #00001000 0 01000000 green
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;192c'#00001000 0 11000000 yellow
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;32c' #00001000 0 00100000 blue
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;160c'#00001000 0 10100000 magenta
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;96c' #00001000 0 01100000 cyan
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;224c'#00001000 0 11100000 dim white
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;16c' #00001000 0 00010000 black     + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;144c'#00001000 0 10010000 red       + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;80c' #00001000 0 01010000 green     + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;208c'#00001000 0 11010000 yellow    + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;48c' #00001000 0 00110000 blue      + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;176c'#00001000 0 10110000 magenta   + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;112c'#00001000 0 01110000 cyan      + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;240c'#00001000 0 11110000 dim white + highlighting
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the **reset** command:

```
reset
```

"The reset command under a BSD/Linux/UNIX operating system is used to restore a console to a normal state. This is useful after a program dies leaving a terminal in an abnormal state."

Answer (score 1):

Whether you *can*, and *how* you can change the text-cursor color depends entirely upon the terminal emulator.  There is no terminfo/termcap capability which corresponds to this feature.

`xterm` is one of (a few) which can do this.  It is documented as one of the *dynamic color* features, e.g., from *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls)*

> **OSC** *Ps* **;** *Pt* **BEL**
>
> Set Text Parameters.  For colors and font, if *Pt* is a "?", the
>   control sequence elicits a response which consists of the control sequence which would set the corresponding value.  The
>   dtterm control sequences allow you to determine the icon name
>   and window title.
>
> *Ps* = 1 2  -> Change text cursor color to *Pt*.

The [`xtermset`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clts/) program know hows to set this and similar features. If there is no cursor-color specified, `xterm` attempts to keep the cursor constantly visible by using the reverse of the cell's foreground and background colors.

Aside from rxvt-unicode (which [documents](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/urxvt.7.html) the feature under *XTerm Operating System Commands*) some other terminal emulators may implement the same thing. However, the usual "MAC" programs (Terminal.app and Iterm2) do not support these control sequences.  Iterm2 has it marked as ["future release"](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1961).

Using [`xtermset`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clts/), you could set the cursor color to green using

```
xtermset -cr green
```

It actually does not do "much": `xterm` accepts a control sequence which could be put in a script as

```
printf '\033]12;green\007'
```

where '`033]` is *OSC* (the operating system control prefix) and `\007` is one of the suffixes accepted for ending the sequence.  A *string terminator* `\033\\` in the printf (escape backslash) would be preferred since it is standard in ECMA-48.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with this info?